# vectorizing seq R

Tags: r, purrr

I want to generate a sequence of time stamps in between two dates

So test frame is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

 test <- tibble(category = c('a', 'b', 'a'),
           start=c('2016-01-01 00:00:10', 
                   '2016-02-01 00:00:20',
                   '2016-03-01 00:00:30'),
           end = c('2016-01-01 00:01:00', 
                   '2016-02-01 00:02:00',
                   '2016-03-01 00:03:00')) %>%
       mutate(start = ymd_hms(start),
              end = ymd_hms(end) )
```

and I want to run:

```
seq(start, end, by=10)
```

for each row and have a sequences in one data frame so result is like:

```
category | timestamp
   a     | 2016-01-01 00:00:10
   a     | 2016-01-01 00:00:20
   a     | 2016-01-01 00:00:30
```

for each row and all of it `rbind` together
I have over 30000 rows so a for loop won't work that well.

I tried to use `purrr` using:

```
gg <- test %>%
  purrr::map( seq(start, end, by=10) )
```

but that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Base r: `Map(function(x,y) seq(x, y, by=10), test $start, test$end)` ... (untested)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `dplyr` alone

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
    group_by(category, n = row_number()) %>% 
    do(data.frame(Seq = seq(.$start, .$end, by = 10))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-n)
```

---

Or using `map` from `purrr`

```
test %>% 
   split(., seq_len(nrow(test))) %>% 
   map_df(~cbind(., Seq = seq(.$start, .$end, by = 10)))
```